# A 'simple' boundary value/ initial value p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

tl/dr: I have a numpy boundary/initial value problem and want to see if I'm approaching this the right way.  I'm fairly new with numpy.  I'm presenting a simplified version of the problem.

I have 2 functions `a` and `b` defined for integer values of `t` and `x`, which I'm trying to calculate for positive `x` and `t` (say up to `N` ).  I want to figure out the best way to do this with numpy.

I have boundary values at `t=0` and `x=0`, `a(t,x)` depends only on `a(t-1,x-1)` and `b(t-1,x-1)`  while `b(t,x)` depends on lots of values of `a` with smaller `t`, `x` .  This is what makes it 'simple'.  We have

`a=1` for `t=0` and for `x=0`.

`b=0.1` for for `t=0` and `b=1` for `x=0`.  At `x=t=0`, we get `b=0.1`.

In the interior, `a(t,x) = a(t-1,x-1) - b(t-1,x-1)`.

Now the hard part.  `b(t,x) =  a(t-1,x-1) S(t, t-1) + a(t-2,x-2) S(t,t-2) + ...`
where `S(t,y)` is a sum equal to `f(a(t-1,1)) + f(a(t-1,2)) + ... + f(a(t-1,y))` for some function `f` (If you need something specific, you could assume it's just `a + a**2`).

So my plan is to do this basically as:

```
   initialize values

   loop over t:
       update a
       loop over y:
           define the S(t,y) #each step is vectorizable I think
       loop over x:
           set b to equal the dot product between vector of S and slice of a.
```

My question: Is this a reasonable approach - can I cut out any of those loops, or should I take a different tack entirely?

Bonus question: Any likely errors for a numpy newb to make coding this?

Comment: please show us the function definitions

Comment: I'd recommend you focus on correctness first using what you know, without too much concern for performance. Once you have a working solution you have a better idea what part the performance bottleneck is and you have a means of verifying the more advanced code you come up with. Also it is easier to receive help on vectorizing your code if you already have a working loopy version.